# Pusher showing already sent data

Tags: python-3.x, vue.js, pusher

I'm using pusher for a python-vuejs app.

I have a function that sends data to the pusher, the data content is `{'message':{'value':id_value}}`

The function is executed via an api rest POST request, when I trigger the function and send the data to the pusher on the page with the url `host/data-url` the pusher console shows the correct informations for the first time.

When I execute the POST request again (without refreshing the page), the data is gotten twice (gotten means that it is physically there not just a pusher console output), if i do the request again it is gotten 3 times and so on.

Does anyone have any idea on how to initialize pusher after each request or something because if I refresh the page and send the data, it works again and i get it only once.

Comment: So you are saying that when you send a message to a channel, client receives it once. 
And when you broadcast a message one more time, client receives two messages instead of only receiving one (last) message?

Are you holding any state in your app? Does your app try to load state when event is received? 

I doubt if it's from Pusher. You can actually enable console log and see how many messages are received on the client side: 
https://pusher.com/docs/channels/getting_started/debugging/#enable-logging-in-the-channels-javascript-library

Comment: I'm not holding states, but i'm sending data with the same event name each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out if anyone have the same problem.

1.You should subscribe the moment you call the page.

2.If you are triggering the channel.bind with a button click (or any event launcher ) , make sure to unbind before the click and not after.